How to connect wifi with a new installed ubuntu live server 22.04 and no net wire plugged in?

Answers about apt install

The googled answers seem like telling me installing net tools by apt, but the awkard thing is  I have not got the net wire, so how apt would do the install job ?

Config wifi

I make sure the ubuntu have told me to add a wifi in the installing ubuntu live server.
What should I do to connect a wifi signal since the ubuntu server can do it, I think I can do it as well !
